# Finding possible pivots after the first quicksort partition

Tags: algorithm, quicksort

The below is a school problem on quicksort:

An array of 7 integers is being sorted using Quicksort. Suppose the algorithm has just finished the first partitioning and pivot swapping thus changing the content of the original array to the following:
[2, 3, 14, 19, 19, 28, 28]
From the above resulting array, how many integers could have been the pivot? Note: elements == pivot are partitioned to the right.

The answer given is 5, but mine's 7 - the reason being that for a number to be a pivot, elements to it's left has to be smaller than it and elements to it's right has to be larger than it. What's the problem with this reasoning? It probably has got something to do with the last sentence, but I'm unsure of why.

Comment: You don't think it's just them counting distinct values only (of which there are 5)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is 5 instead of 7 because 19 and 28 are repeated two times and, thus, not distinct numbers. The answer is

2, 3, 14, 19, 28

what is exatly 5 **distinct** integers